# Java count troubleshooting/bug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, user-interface

I am working on a project for my computer programming class and have come across a weird bug I can't seem to fix. When adding new accounts and then deleting them, it seems to add more to the variable **count** than needed and seems to loop inside the **actionlisteners()** method which causes it to "store values" and create more accounts instead of just one. I have done some testing and the bug only happens after you have deleted and added an account once. **Counts** value will go from 1 to 3 when there is only one area it increments. How can I fix this?

```
    public static void actionlisteners(){
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            sel1 = cb1.getSelectedItem();
            sel2 = cb2.getSelectedItem();
            if(sel1.toString().equals("-----BankAccounts-----") && !sel2.toString().equals("Add Account")){
                l1.setText("Please select an account.");
                actionlisteners();
            }
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Add Account")){
                if(count != 20){
                    count++;
                    cb1.addItem(t1.getText().toString());
                    t1.setText("");
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
                else{
                    l1.setText("You can create a maximum of 20 accounts.");
                }
            }
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Delete Account")){
                if(count > 0 && !sel1.toString().equals("-----BankAccounts-----")){
                count--;
                if(!sel1.toString().equals("-----BankAccounts-----")){
                cb1.removeItem(sel1.toString());
                System.out.println(count);
                }
                }
                if(count == 0){
                    l1.setText("There are no more accounts to remove!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    cb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            sel2 = cb2.getSelectedItem();
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Add Account")){
                l1.setText("You are adding a new account.");
            }
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Deposit Money")){
                l1.setText("You are depositing money.");
            }
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Withdraw Money")){
                l1.setText("You are withdrawing money.");
            }
            if(sel2.toString().equals("Delete Account")){
                l1.setText("You are deleting an account.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: Thanks for the help! Not sure how I missed that extra call of actionlisteners();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `actionlisteners();` inside the `if(sel1.toString().equals("-----BankAccounts-----") && ...` statement registers another action listener for the component `b1`. That means if you press the button `b1` (I guess it is a button) the action `Add` or `Delete` will be performed twice.
Make sure that you create only one action listener.